# How do I set the value of an input-element via jQuery, when I only know it's "name"-attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to reset some text-boxes which only have an unique name (not an unique id).
I tried it with jQuery, but my code seems to do nothing:

```
$('input[name=customergroupname]').value="";
```

Comment: `$('input[name=customergroupname]').val("");`

Comment: @zerkms answers are already here

Comment: @rubish dude put it as answer anyways, I will vote! B-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('input[name="customergroupname"]').val("");
```

Answer (score 3):

Getting and setting value of form elements wrapped in a jQuery object is being done with use jQuery `val` function:

```
$('input[name="customergroupname"]').val("");
```

`.value` can only be used for DOM elements, like this:

```
$('input[name="customergroupname"]').eq(0).value ="";

$(...)       // This is a jQuery object.
$(...)[n]    // This is a DOM object in the nth place in the set.
$(...).eq(n) // This is a DOM object in the nth place in the set.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/vN74v/2/

**Code**

```
$('#hullk').click(function(){ // in example when you click the button
    $('input[name="customergroupname"]').val("");
});
​
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [DOM level 2 specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-form-element.html#the-form-element), you can access:

```
document.forms["foo"].elements["customergroupname"].value = '';
```

If `formName` and `fieldName` are constants rather than variables you can use literal syntax:

```
document.forms.foo.elements.customergroupname.value = '';
```

Answer (score -3):

try:

```
$('input[name="customergroupname"]').value="";
```

I've wrapped `customergroupname` in quotes.

Very true, I mixed the quotes up. Edited now.

Comment: It's even worse now! :( You mixed with the quotes and now `customergroupname` is a variable.

Comment: I'm afraid it's still wrong, please see my answer about `.val` V.S. `.value`